# INSTAGRAM ONLINE ACCESS

Tags: anonymity

I had a problem trying to access Instagram on my regular browser due to too many sign-in attempts.  Now when I tried to create a new account, I get a message that says "Sorry, something went wrong creating your account. Please try again soon." I'm certain the website is blocking new account creation attempts from my computer.  So I thought by installing Tor it would help make it appear as if I'm creating a new account from a different location and go smoothly but I still get the same message from Instagram.  Can anyone explain why this is happening?  Thanks